# Favoriting system on Appengine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have the following model structure

```
class User(db.Model) :
nickname = db.StringProperty(required=True)
fullname = db.StringProperty(required=True)

class Article(db.Model) :
title = db.StringProperty(required=True)
body = db.StringProperty(required=True)
author = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True)

class Favorite(db.Model) :
who = db.ReferenceProperty(User, required=True)
what = db.ReferenceProperty(Article, required=True)
```

I'd like to display 10 last articles according to this pattern: 
article.title, article.body, article.author(nickname), info if this article has been already favorited by the signed in user.

I have added a function which I use to get the authors of these articles using only one query ([it is described here](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/01/ReferenceProperty-prefetching-in-App-Engine))

But I don't know what to do with the favorites (I'd like to know which of the displayed articles have been favorited by me using less than 10 queries (I want to display 10 articles)). Is it possible?

Comment: Question: your Favorites class has a reference to Authors. My guess is that Authors is meant to refer to the person doing the favoriting rather than the person who wrote the Article that is being favorited. Am I correct?

Comment: In fact, class Authors is used to store all the users

Comment: The model names are a little confusing to me.  I would probably make all of these singular nouns since each `Articles` entity actually refers to one article, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually do this with an *amortized* cost of **0 queries** if you denormalize your data more!  Add a `favorites` property to `Authors` which stores a list of keys of articles which the user has favorited.  Then you can determine if the article is the user's favorite by simply checking this list.

If you retrieve this list of favorites when the user first logs in and just store it in your user's session data (and update it when the user adds/removes a favorite), then you won't have to query the datastore to check to see if an item is a favorite.

---

Suggested update to the `Authors` model:

```
class Authors(db.Model):  # I think this would be better named "User"
    # same properties you already had ...
    favorites = db.ListProperty(db.Key, required=True, default=[])
```

When the user logs in, just cache their list of favorites in your session data:

```
session['favs'] = user.favorites
```

Then when you show the latest articles, you can check if they are a favorite just by seeing if each article's key is in the favorites list you cached already (or you could dynamically query the favorites list but there is really no need to).

```
favs = session['favs']
articles = get_ten_latest_articles()
for article in articles:
    if article.key() in favs:
        # ...
```

Comment: Thank you for your advice. That's the solution I think.

Answer (score 1):

I think there is one more solution.
Let's add 'auto increment' fields to the User and Article class.
Then, when we want to add an entry to the Favorite class, we will also add the key name in the format which we will be able to know having auto increment value of the signed in user and the article, like this 'UserId'+id_of_the_user+'ArticleId'+id_of_an_article.

Then, when it comes to display, we will easily predict key names of the favorites and would be able to use Favorite.get_by_key_name(key_names).

Answer (score 0):

An alternative solution to dound's is to store the publication date of the favorited article on the Favorite entry. Then, simply sort by that when querying.